# Примитив или что-то другое?

Tags: java, ооп, переменные, типы-данных, типы

В языке программирования *Java* всё является объектом, исключение составляют примитивы. Контейнером для примитивов являются переменные примитивных типов, с этим особых вопросов у меня не возникает. А теперь мне хотелось бы перейти к сути. Чем же является содержимое переменных ссылочных типов данных? Насколько мне известно, то переменные ссылочных типов просто хранят адреса объектов в памяти. Что же представляет собой сам адрес? Очевидно, что это не объект. Корректно ли в таком случае утверждение о том, что адреса, которые хранятся в ссылочных переменных также являются примитивами? Или же это что-то иное? Меня интересует именно вопрос класификации.

Comment: мне кажется это другой уровень абстракции. Тоиесть, все оъекты, но что тгда ссылка на объект? это уже лежит на более низком уровне и нет смысла смешивать понятия. Дальше уже будут адреса памяти, кеш процессора, инструкции, алу. Но смысл лезть дальше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вопрос терминологии. Да, фактически адреса являются примитивами. Но в спецификации примитивы и ссылки строго разделены, потому что примитивность ссылок проявляется лишь при чтении/записи в память, а при любых осмысленных операциях используется информация, хранящаяся в куче и доступная по этим ссылкам, а не в самих значениях, как у настоящих примитивов.

Answer (score 0):

> В спецификации Java не содержит конкретной информации о данных,
>   хранящихся в ссылке. Во многих JVM ссылка реализована исключительно
>   как указатель и занимает 32 бита в 32-битных JVM и 64 бита — в
>   64-битных. Тем не менее, существуют реализации JVM (например, Zing
>   Virtual Machine от Azul), в целях оптимизации помещающие в ссылку
>   также информацию о типе данных. Другие (непример, Java HotSpot Virtual
>   Machine), наоборот, используют технологию «Compressed Oops»,
>   позволяющую использовать ссылки размером в 32 бита на 64-битных
>   операционных системах.

Подробнее: http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_(Java)

Comment: Так и не понял, как её можно класифицировать? Её нужно рассматривать как обособленную сущность? Выходит, что в языке программирования *Java* существуют объекты, примитивы и отдельно ссылки? Или как?